# .htaccess causing 500 internal server error on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /localhost/htaccess_pwd/main/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "You need to be authorized!!"
Require valid-user

<Files "page1.php">
Require valid-user
</Files>
```

In the above code I want to protect a file i.e page1.php and even while hitting the url it asks me for username and password.But after putting username and password it says,

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Please help to fix it.

Comment: general rule: if you get a 500, you FIRST go look at the server log to get details about the 500.

Comment: Is this path correct? /localhost/htaccess_pwd/main/.htpasswd

Comment: @MarcB It throws the following error:

[Wed Jul 27 21:39:45.232063 2016] [authn_file:error] [pid 3460:tid 1588] (OS 3)The system cannot find the path specified.  : [client 127.0.0.1:60661] AH01620: Could not open password file: C:/localhost/htaccess_pwd/main/.htpasswd

Comment: @error2007s No :( it is not correct. can you help me get the right path?

Comment: Well you have to know that path what path did you use while creating the password?

Comment: @error2007s well .htpasswd  is in the same folder where .htaccess is placed i.e main.

Comment: So change this path /localhost/htaccess_pwd/main/.htpasswd with the correct path to .htpasswd file

Comment: @error2007s Thanks.I got the right path and it started working :)

Comment: Should I write down a answer for this

Comment: Yes please.But I got that right URL.

You can have a look on my another question asked now. 

Thanks

Comment: @error2007s please have a look on this URL,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632183/make-an-url-password-protected-from-direct-accessing-htaccess/38632349#38632349

Answer (score 0):

The issue in you htaccess is regarding the path see below. I don't think "Localhost" can be a path. Change that path to correct path and it will start working.

```
AuthUserFile <correct path to htpassword>/.htpasswd
```