# make an url password protected from direct accessing htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to `.htaccess` . I have two files named `page1.php` and `page2.php`,while `page2.php` is in another folder and `page1.php` has a link to it.I want to make `page2.php` password protected when someone wants to open `page2.php` directly hitting the URL.
But it should be open when someone wants to go to that page from `page1.php` page.

Can anyone help me out to get this done?

Note:I have already added the following thing to my .htaccess . But here this page is password protected in both ways no matter someone open it directly or go to that page from `page1.php` . I want to make it password protected only when directly want to go to that page.

```
AuthUserFile C:/wamp/www/htaccess_pwd/main/.htpasswd.txt 
AuthType Basic
AuthName "You need to be authorized!!"
Require valid-user

<Files "page2.php">
Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Comment: @error2007s Please help me out bro.

Answer (score 0):

Solution1:

If you are dealing with .php files, i think its the easiest to code this in php.
page1.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["log"]="ok";
?>
```

page2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["log"])){
?>
//your site
<?php }else{ ?>
You are not allowed to enter!!!
<?php } ?>
```

Solution2:

Include the password into the link on page1.php (will cause errors on some browsers)

```
<a href="user:password@http://yourserver/page2.php">Log In</a>
```

Comment: It's the right way using session but I want here to set it in .htaccess file.

Comment: The only other way i know see solution 2

Comment: solution2? let me check

Comment: That too looks good if I need to do that in php but unfortunately I will have to get this thing done with .htaccess.

Anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: The second solution is pure html + htaccess no php

Comment: But here password is needed no matter if an user hit the URL directly or he go to page from page1.php. 

I only need to make it protected when an user hits the link directly on browser

Comment: You use your htaccess to protect the page. The link ive provided enters the password automatically so the user does not need to do so